# dmatrices don't see a column

Tags: python, patsy

I have this code below that suppose to create 2 dataframes on giving columns. df's Region column has 5 variables; W,E,N,S and C. However the resulted dataframe has only W,E,N,S and an intercept column.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from patsy import dmatrices
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Guerry','HistData').data
vars = ['Department','Lottery','Literacy','Wealth','Region']
df = df[vars]
df = df.dropna()
#      Department  Lottery  Literacy  Wealth Region
# 0           Ain       41        37      73      E
# 1         Aisne       38        51      22      N
# 2        Allier       66        13      61      C
# 3  Basses-Alpes       80        46      76      E
# 4  Hautes-Alpes       79        69      83      E

y, X = dmatrices('Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region', data=df, return_type='dataframe')
print(X.columns.tolist())
# ['Intercept', 'Region[T.E]', 'Region[T.N]', 'Region[T.S]', 'Region[T.W]', 'Literacy', 'Wealth']
```

When I change to last row as below it works fine and shows 5 Region values on
the dataframe.

```
y, X = dmatrices('Literacy + Wealth + Region ~ Lottery', data=df, return_type='dataframe')
print(y.columns.tolist())
# ['Region[C]', 'Region[E]', 'Region[N]', 'Region[S]', 'Region[W]', 'Literacy', 'Wealth']
```

Can someone please explain it what is the reason of this? and what is the intercept column created on the first code instead of Region C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patsy [automatically adds a constant "Intercept" term](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html#intercept-handling) to the right-hand side of
formulas.  This leads to a design matrix with an Intercept column of all 1's.
[For example](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import patsy

data = patsy.demo_data("a", "b", "y")
#     a   b         y
# 0  a1  b1  1.764052
# 1  a1  b2  0.400157
# 2  a2  b1  0.978738
# 3  a2  b2  2.240893
# 4  a1  b1  1.867558
# 5  a1  b2 -0.977278
# 6  a2  b1  0.950088
# 7  a2  b2 -0.151357

mat = patsy.dmatrices("y ~ a + b ", data, return_type='dataframe')[1]
print(mat)
```

yields

```
   Intercept  a[T.a2]  b[T.b2]
0        1.0      0.0      0.0
1        1.0      0.0      1.0
2        1.0      1.0      0.0
3        1.0      1.0      1.0
4        1.0      0.0      0.0
5        1.0      0.0      1.0
6        1.0      1.0      0.0
7        1.0      1.0      1.0
```

Patsy analyzes the expressions on each side of the formula, and [only adds new
terms when such a term is needed](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html#redundancy-and-categorical-factors) to add the required flexibility to the
model.  In terms of the design matrix, this means that a new column is not added
unless the vector space spanned by the columns is expanded by the addition of
the new column. In other words, a new column which is already in the span of the
other columns would be redundant and so it is not added.

When you have a categorical variable which must equal W, E, N, S, or C, knowing that the value of the variable is not W, E, N, or S is equivalent to knowing the variable equals C.

Look at the output from the previous example. Knowing that the `a` variable
is not `a2` is equivalent to knowing it equals `a1`. In terms of the design
matrix, the column space would not be increased by including an `a1` column, since
`Intercept - a2` is `a1`. (Below, the `a1` column is labeled `a[T.a1]`, and
similarly for `a2`):

```
   Intercept  a[T.a2]  b[T.b2]  a[T.a1]
0        1.0      0.0      0.0      1.0
1        1.0      0.0      1.0      1.0
2        1.0      1.0      0.0      0.0
3        1.0      1.0      1.0      0.0
4        1.0      0.0      0.0      1.0
5        1.0      0.0      1.0      1.0
6        1.0      1.0      0.0      0.0
7        1.0      1.0      1.0      0.0
```

Similarly, in your situation, no column is added for the categorical value C,
because Intercept - (W + E + N + S) equals C.

---

Now we can return to your original code and understand the result more clearly:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from patsy import dmatrices

df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Guerry','HistData').data
vars_ = ['Department','Lottery','Literacy','Wealth','Region']
df = df[vars_]
df = df.dropna()

formula1 = 'Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region'
print(formula1)
y1, X1 = dmatrices(formula1, data=df, return_type='dataframe')
print('LHS: {}'.format(y1.columns.tolist()))
# ['Lottery'], 
print('RHS: {}'.format(X1.columns.tolist()))
# ['Intercept', 'Region[T.E]', 'Region[T.N]', 'Region[T.S]', 'Region[T.W]', 'Literacy', 'Wealth']

formula2 = 'Literacy + Wealth + Region ~ Lottery'
print(formula2)

y2, X2 = dmatrices(formula2, data=df, return_type='dataframe')
print('LHS: {}'.format(y2.columns.tolist()))
# ['Region[C]', 'Region[E]', 'Region[N]', 'Region[S]', 'Region[W]', 'Literacy', 'Wealth']
print('RHS: {}'.format(X2.columns.tolist()))
# ['Intercept', 'Lottery']
```

Notice that an `Intercept` has been automatically added to the *right-hand side*
of each formula.  When there is both an Intercept term and a categorical
variable on the same side of the formula, one value of the categorical variable
is always missing because its presence would not expand the design matrix's
column space.

---

You can tell patsy to not add an Intercept column by including `+ 0` on the right-hand side of the formula, or by including `- 1`. They both [do the same thing](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html#intercept-handling).

```
formula3 = 'Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region + 0'
print(formula3)
y1, X1 = dmatrices(formula3, data=df, return_type='dataframe')
print('LHS: {}'.format(y1.columns.tolist()))
print('RHS: {}'.format(X1.columns.tolist()))
```

Now, the right-hand side has a `Region[C]` column:

```
LHS: ['Lottery']
RHS: ['Region[C]', 'Region[E]', 'Region[N]', 'Region[S]', 'Region[W]', 'Literacy', 'Wealth']
```